# Open Up MATLAB GUI With Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, matlab, child-process

At work we have a limited number of MATLAB license keys and a website that tells you if any are available. I wrote a node app which polls the website and then when a key is available it starts MATLAB. I'm currently doing:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec; 
exec('/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab');
```

to run the matlab binary but the process just runs in the background and the MATLAB gui doesn't show up. Is there any way to make the gui show up and as a bonus is there a way to allow the matlab process to keep running even if I stop the node script?

Comment: Try the `-r` command line argument and putting your command in a shell or bash file that you then run from node. Play around with exec vs execFile vs spawn.

Comment: The -r didn't work, but then I looked at the matlab documentation and I had to use the -desktop flag and it is now working!

Comment: (remember you can self answer your own question :) --- and please do if you solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the `-desktop` flag to my command:

```
exec('/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab -desktop');
```